# How to get dynamically set Nav Host using findNavController from <FrameLayout /> and not from <Fragment />?

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I have defined the code in XML, for nav host in FrameLayout so as to dynamically create Nav Host.

```
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_nav_host_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

When trying to access it using `findNavController` from MainActivity...

```
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.main_nav_host_fragment)
        findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation_view)
            .setupWithNavController(navController)
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            if(destination.id == R.id.signupFragment) {
                bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE
            } else {
                bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
```

I get the error: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.example.client.ui.main.MainActivity@516bd45 does not have a NavController set on 2131296657`

Answer (score 1):

```
val finalHost = NavHostFragment.create(R.navigation.example_graph)
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.nav_host, finalHost)
    .setPrimaryNavigationFragment(finalHost) // equivalent to app:defaultNavHost="true"
    .commit()
```

for more details got to 
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic